# Most efficient try/finally/dispose

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ternary-operator, try-finally

I have this method where I may pass a DbContext or I may not:

```
public static List<ClaimService> GetServicesForAccountType(DatabaseContainer db,Guid claimId, Guid accountTypeId)
{
    bool dispose = (db == null ? true :false);
    try
    {
        db = (db ==  null ?  new DatabaseContainer(): db);
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<ClaimService>("SELECT * FROM dbo.ClaimService WHERE ClaimId = '@p1' AND AccountTypeId = '@p2'", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("p1", claimId), new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("p2", accountTypeId)).ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dispose) { db.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

I am doing 2 ternary operations, 1 to determine if I should do a dispose and another to determine if I need to create a new dbContext.

Question:  Both ternary ops are the exact same condition `(db == null)`, is there a way I can set my `dispose` and my `db` variables in one op?

Comment: Thanks for the options guys.  I prefer to not define another var and re-use db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first statement can be rewritten as

```
bool dispose = db == null;
```

and the second as

```
db = db ?? new DatabaseContainer();
```

See the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for this last option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dispose` in second check:

```
db = (dispose ?  new DatabaseContainer() : db);
```

or use null-coalescing operator:

```
db = db ?? new DatabaseContainer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to dispose `db` if you were responsible for creating it, but use the one passed and do not dispose if not. You could do something like:

```
public static List<ClaimService> GetServicesForAccountType(DatabaseContainer db,Guid claimId, Guid accountTypeId)
{
    DatabaseContaner localScopeDbContainer = null;

    try
    {
        db = db ?? (localScopeDbContainer = new DatabaseContainer());
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<ClaimService>("SELECT * FROM dbo.ClaimService WHERE ClaimId = '@p1' AND AccountTypeId = '@p2'", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("p1", claimId), new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("p2", accountTypeId)).ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (localScopeDbContainer != null)
            localScopeDbContainer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You could even skip the `db =` and do a one-liner:

```
public static List<ClaimService> GetServicesForAccountType(DatabaseContainer db,Guid claimId, Guid accountTypeId)
{
    DatabaseContaner localScopeDbContainer = null;

    try
    {
        return (db ?? (localScopeDbContainer = new DatabaseContainer()).Database.SqlQuery<ClaimService>("SELECT * FROM dbo.ClaimService WHERE ClaimId = '@p1' AND AccountTypeId = '@p2'", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("p1", claimId), new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("p2", accountTypeId)).ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (localScopeDbContainer != null)
            localScopeDbContainer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how much readability any of this gets you.